# Flask SQLAlchemy querying a model not returning the Foreign Key

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following classes:

```py
class CompanyModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tb_company"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))


class CustomerModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tb_customer"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    company_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                           db.ForeignKey(CompanyModel.id),
                           nullable=False)

    company = db.relationship("CompanyModel",
                              foreign_keys=company_id,
                              backref=db.backref("company",
                                                 uselist=False))
```

However, when I query it, the foreign keys won't show:

```json
{
    "id": 79
}
```

I've even tried to manually set its attribute at the query, but it won't work anyway:

```py
@classmethod
def find_by_id(cls, customer_id: int) -> "CustomerModel":
    customer = cls.query.filter_by(id=customer_id).first()
    setattr(customer, "company_id", customer.company.id)
    return customer
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it. Just added the field to the Flask-Marshmallow's auto schema:

```py
class CustomerSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerModel
        load_instance = True

    id = ma.auto_field(dump_only=True)
    company_id = ma.auto_field(dump_only=True)
```

However, i still have an issue... I would like to use another field from "CompanyModel" as the result of the query, for instance, the "name" column. However, when I try to manually set it, i have the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Company Name'
```

How could I do it?